# Youtube video popup works on Mac and ios but not on ANY PC

Tags: html, css, video, youtube, popup

I have built a website that has a popup to a youtube video when the visitor clicks on the play button, below is my code. It works on iPad, iPhone and Mac but will not work on a PC. Would somebody be kind enough to explain to me what I have done wrong and why the popup will not open to the youtube video on a PC? The link still works as I can open the video in a New Tab, it just wont open automatically in the pop up. I have tested it on 3 PC's but nothing.

Thanks guys.

HTML

```
<div class="description centerAbsolute">
    <h1 class="proximaBold antialiased"><span class="style8">BIG</span>SMILE</h1>
    <h2 class="proximaLite antialiased">Cambridge</h2>
    <a href="http://youtu.be/krlR2-YGk4sI" target="_blank" class="play clearfix proximaBold relative"><span class="cta floatL">through the eyes of a customer</span><span class="playIco floatL"></span></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* --- VIDEO --- */
#main>header>.video>#youtube{opacity: 0; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);}
#main>header>.video>#youtube>.close{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0px;
}
#main>header>.video>#youtube>.close>a{
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: url(../img/close%402x.png) no-repeat center;
    background-color: #32ADC3;
    background-size: 40px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
#main>header>.video{width:100%; height:500px; background:url(../img/bg-video.jpg) no-    repeat center top; background-size:cover; color:#FFF; }
#main>header>.video>.description{width:700px; margin-top:-185px; margin-left:-350px; text-align:center;}
#main>header>.video>.description>h1{font-size:118px; line-height:118px; margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; letter-spacing:0.12em;}
#main>header>.video>.description>h2{font-size:36px;line-height:35px;  margin:15px 0px 0px 0px; letter-spacing:0.12em; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;}
#main>header>.video>.description>.play{text-decoration:none; color:#FFF; display:block; height:70px; width:650px; margin:40px auto 40px auto; background:#32ADC3;}
#main>header>.video>.description>.play>.playIco{ display:block; width:70px; height:70px; background:url(../img/play-ico.png) center no-repeat; border-left:solid 1px    #32ADC3;}
#main>header>.video>.description>.play>.cta{ width:578px; font-size:16px; text-transform:uppercase; line-height:72px; letter-spacing:0.25em;-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;}
#main>header>.video>.description>.share{ width:140px; margin:auto;}
#main>header>.video>.description>.share>h3{width:136px; font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:auto; text-align:center; letter-spacing:0.3em;}
#main>header>.video>.description>.share>h3>.title{ margin:auto 18px auto 18px;}
#main>header>.video>.description>.share>h3>.line{ display:block; width:20px; height:1px; margin-top:5%; border-top:solid 1px #FFF;}
#main>header>.video>.description>.share>ul{ margin-left:-8px; margin-bottom:0px;}
#main>header>.video>.description>.share>ul>li{width:25%;}
#main>header>.video>.description>.share>ul>li>a{ display:block; width:30px; height:30px; border-radius:15px;}
#main>header>.video>.description>.share>ul>li>a:hover{ background-color:#32ADC3;}
#main>header>.video>.description>.share>ul>li>a>img{ margin-top:6px; text-align:center;}
```

Amendment : My problem is very precise, and nobody has yet solved the issue, so I know it's not really allowed but if you visit www.mildenhire.com/bigsmile you will see the website there and the video option loads immediately and is the first thing you see. I have no idea why it works on mac and iOS but not on PC. Could somebody please visit this page, troubleshoot it and tell me what I have done wrong? This has been a big learning curve. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would try the iframe embed instead:

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/krlR2-YGk4s?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: where would i put it?

Comment: Amendment : My problem is very precise, and nobody has yet solved the issue, so I know it's not really allowed but if you visit www.mildenhire.com/bigsmile you will see the website there and the video option loads immediately and is the first thing you see. I have no idea why it works on mac and iOS but not on PC. Could somebody please visit this page, troubleshoot it and tell me what I have done wrong? This has been a big learning curve. Thanks